# Async Load of Firebase Array of Images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire with my Ionic project. I do convert the user images on upload and store them as base64 strings in firebase. Please note : Each image takes only around 60-150 KB only. Also each user can have only 9 images.

I'm currently facing an issue, when a user profile is visited the images wont load till all the images are fetched. Below is the service that fetches the array of image data from Firebase.. As you can see the data is only passed to the controller on $loaded

```
return $firebaseArray(API.photos.child(userKey)).$loaded();
```

> $loaded : Returns a promise which is resolved when the initial array data has
>   been downloaded from the database. The promise resolves to the
>   $firebaseArray.

What I basically need is each image to be added to the **ng-repeat** as they arrive rather than waiting for the whole batch. How can I achieve this or what are the alternatives

*Note : The return data consists of an array of base64strings

Answer (score 1):

FYI Firebase now has [file storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) so you don't have to do this. But ok, still want to use base64?

You can do something like this:

```
// get user
$scope.user = {name: 'bob', prof_imgs: [43, 44]};
// create map to store images
$scope.img_map = {};

// download each image individually and asynchronously
user.prof_imgs.forEach(function(id){
  ref.child('images/'+id).once("value", function(data) {
    $scope.img_map[id] = data;
  });
});

// display with angular
<img ng-repeat="id in user.prof_imgs" 
     data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{img_map[id]}}" 
     ng-if="img_map[id]"/>
```